# Populate helper table with dynamic data based on date

Tags: excel

Looking for formula to populate `TABLE 1` `TOTAL HRS` from `PAY WEEK` total hours cell under each date like SUNDAY 10/15/2017. basically in `TABLE 1` "if PAY WEEK::B2 = TABLE 1::A289 then B289 = PAY WEEK::C5" but since the B row in PAY WEEK is dynamic... How can this be done?

Dates in `PAY WEEK` are set by: B2 is `IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),)=1,TODAY(),TODAY()−WEEKDAY(TODAY()−1,))` B3 is `B2+1` and daily total 3 rows down...

[image]

[image]

EDIT: here is structure of example tried:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Basically, if you need to preserve historical values in `TOTAL HOURS` column, you will need to use a VBA to do that or copy paste-value manually every week. If this is not your concern, the formula you can retrieve values for `TABLE 1` from `PAY WEEK` is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$5:$O$5,,MATCH(A13,$B$2:$O$2,0)+1),"")
```

**EDIT:**

Per OP, the following formula would work for `Mac Numbers`:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(PAY WEEK::$B$5:$O$5,0,MATCH(A290,PAY WEEK::$B$2:$O$2,0)+1),"")
```

Comment: can't use VBA (this is actually a Mac Numbers table) - That would work for SUNDAY only date but how would it get correct totals for E5, G5, I5, K5...? I was thinking I needed something like this with nested IF statements: `=IF(A290=IF(E290=7,PAY WEEK::B$2,),PAY WEEK::C$5,),
IF(A290=IF(E290=1,PAY WEEK::D$2,),PAY WEEK::E$5,),
IF(A290=IF(E290=2,PAY WEEK::F$2,),PAY WEEK::G$5,),
IF(A290=IF(E290=3,PAY WEEK::H$2,),PAY WEEK::I$5,),
IF(A290=IF(E290=4,PAY WEEK::J$2,),PAY WEEK::K$5,),
IF(A290=IF(E290=5,PAY WEEK::L$2,),PAY WEEK::M$5,),
IF(A290=IF(E290=6,PAY WEEK::N$2,),PAY WEEK::O$5,)
`

Comment: I only meant the VBA will not work in Mac. This is what I've tried per your suggestion and not working? `IFERROR(INDEX(PAY WEEK::$B$5:$O$5,,MATCH(A290,PAY WEEK::$B$2:$O$2,0)+1,),"")`

Comment: see my edit above of your example that produces no error but blank cell

Comment: Like I said this is Mac Numbers not Excel - so don't have same tools. this edit i pasted above is the mac equivalent of that...

Comment: functions are the same I'm told, and don't see a "numbers" tag, only difference I see is my version is asking for `row-index` and `area-index`

Comment: Maybe you can try this (I am guessing): `IFERROR(INDEX(PAY WEEK::$B$5:$O$5,0,MATCH(A290,PAY WEEK::$B$2:$O$2,0)+1),"")`. The idea is to add `0` to `row-index` and remove `area-index`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much, update your answer above to I can accept it....

Comment: I know you mentioned the VBA if I wanted to retain history... which is actually what I need to do. Wanted to know if there is a way to have it only change the cell if the current week number matched the week number in my `TABLE 1` "D" column ?

Comment: Formulas are alive and they will be changed based on the setup of the current condition  For example, you can match week# 42 for current week but your prior week (#41) will become invalid with the formula.  Thus, you either have to copy-paste value every week or use VBA to do the trick for you.

Comment: thats what I thought... was hoping for another solution to retain the history.

Comment: It will be so cool to have that function so let's hope Microsoft will find a way to do that in the near future.